# In container with flex-grow: 1 the content is overflowing when it should be scrollable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that is flex-grow sized to fill up the remaining space within a fixed size container.

Within the flex-grow container, I have another div that is a lot bigger than the flex sized container. How do I make it so that the `content-wrapper` element is scrollable instead of the child element overflowing.

Thank you!

```css
.main-content-container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 550px;
    background: green;
}

.sub-content-container {
  width: 300px;
  background: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-container {
  height: 10000px;
  background: #555;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-content-container'>
  <p>stuff</p>
  <div class='sub-content-container'>
    <p>header</p>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
       <div class="content-container">I WANT THIS TO STAY WITHIN THE CONTENT-WRAPPER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, for the `overflow` property to work, the container needs to be overflowed. That requires a fixed length on the container. Without a fixed length (height or width), there's nothing to trigger an overflow. The `flex-grow` property doesn't establish a fixed length, so it doesn't work.

Of course, setting a fixed height on your container is not an option if you want a dynamic layout.

So, to solve both problems, set the container to `height: 1px`.

- this establishes the fixed length;
- it doesn't interfere with the dynamic lengths; and,
- the `flex-grow` property expands the container to full height

But there's one more problem. The nested flex container in column direction seems to be ignoring the `overflow` property. This is possibly because of the nesting in a flex formatting context. Hence, if possible, switch that container back to a block formatting context.

Make these adjustments to your code:

```
.content-wrapper {
  height: 1px; /* new */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
.main-content-container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 550px;
    background: green;
}

.sub-content-container {
  width: 300px;
  background: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 1px; /* new */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-container {
  height: 10000px;
  background: #555;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-content-container'>
  <p>stuff</p>
  <div class='sub-content-container'>
    <p>header</p>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
       <div class="content-container">I WANT THIS TO STAY WITHIN THE CONTENT-WRAPPER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sr8L25xn/)